# C# issue with setting array value for sending request to a web service

Tags: c#, arrays, debugging, enums

in my code I'm creating a ValuationRequest object to send to a web service and return a bunch of diary slots.

One of the fields ValuationType is an array of SearchType[] which can either be .sales or .lettings  and defaults to sales if not specified

```
            request = new ValuationRequest
            {
                ValuationType = new SearchType[] { SearchType.lettings },
                Postcode = model.Postcode,
                FromDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24),
                ToDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14)
            };
```

The above code is being sent to the web service and bringing back sales valuations.

How can I debug this and check why the ValuationType setting is being ignored? I've tried stuff like 
            Debug.WriteLine(request.ValuationType.ToString());
and 
            Debug.WriteLine(request.ValuationType.GetValue());

but don't get anything useful returned. I need ValuationType to be set to lettings.

any help at all is apprecaited

Comment: Since it is an array, you actually may want to do `request.ValuationType[0].ToString()`, because you say that you only have one item in this array. However, you generally don't need to check that `ValuationType` has been set, it won't help you to understand why it is "ignored". What you may want to do is to use Fiddler to see what request has actually been sent, and then continue investigation in the correct direction.

Comment: First, when working with web services I strongly suggest that you setup Fiddler to intercept your traffic to and from that web service. I recently also had a similar issue where some of the request parameters I was sending were not getting serialized.  
So, get Fiddler up and running and see if your property is getting serialized and sent over the wire.    
Furthermore, If you are using WCF, there might be a property on your request named ValuationTypeSpecified. Try setting it to true and see if that helps.

Comment: Cheers, I'll set up Fiddler. ValuationTypeSpecified used to part of the service but has recently been removed. I had that issue before!

However, it seems my ValuationType isn't actually being held long enough to get sent through to the service. It looks  like it's being dropped when passing the request object between two actions...

Answer (score -1):

You can use linq Aggregate operator
Example:

`var debugstr= request.ValuationType.Select(vt=>vt.ToString()).Aggregate( (s1,s2) => s1+ "," s2);`